# Issue while slicing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm facing an issue while trying to slice datas in a pandas dataframe. I have a dataframe which size is 6 columns and more than 22000 rows. 
I want to slice it in a little dataframe using this line of code :

```
logs = pd.DataFrame(list(storLogs.find({"idPlc": ObjectId("5c5ae7187910e20087489296")})))
y1 = logs.loc[logs['idType'] == '5c6c189d319f83008487ba3a']
```

This id exists in multiple rows in the dataframe but when I execute the code, it returns an empty dataframe.

Here is what is returned what I use logs.head()

```
   __v                       _id           createdAt  \
0    0  5c6fbbd5bf8272006ce0c8d1 2019-02-22 09:07:33   
1    0  5c6fbbd5bf8272006ce0c8d2 2019-02-22 09:07:33   
2    0  5c6fbbd5bf8272006ce0c8d3 2019-02-22 09:07:33   
3    0  5c6fbc11bf8272006ce0c8e3 2019-02-22 09:08:33   
4    0  5c6fbc11bf8272006ce0c8e4 2019-02-22 09:08:33   

                      idPlc                    idType  value  
0  5c5ae7187910e20087489296  5c6c189d319f83008487ba3a  29378  
1  5c5ae7187910e20087489296  5c6fbb33319f83008487ba3b  17294  
2  5c5ae7187910e20087489296  5c6fbb3a319f83008487ba3c  10012  
3  5c5ae7187910e20087489296  5c6c189d319f83008487ba3a  29378  
4  5c5ae7187910e20087489296  5c6fbb33319f83008487ba3b  17294
```

Comment: `y1 = logs[logs['idType'] == '5c6c189d319f83008487ba3a']`?

Comment: Sorry my post wasn't very clear I updated it now, but this line is used to slice the dataframe

Comment: can you do a `logs.head()` and then update the question with it's output?

Comment: It look like your first value itself is the `idType` you want to filter out, can you just do `logs['idType'] == '5c6c189d319f83008487ba3a'` and see if there is a true at the beginning of the list that is returned?

Comment: I've already try to output the boolean table and I have only false values

Answer (score 0):

One of other possible solutions is to use `df.query`, where your can
also specify criteria to select rows, e.g.:

```
logs.query("idType == '5c6c189d319f83008487ba3a'")
```

A factor supporting this concept is that especially for big DataFrames, *query* is quite an effective solution.

Comment: Incorrect a boolean list works in `df.loc[]` , The part about `df.query()` is accurate though.

Comment: Even with the .query function it doesn't work, it returns an empty dataframe. I dont understand why.

Comment: Maybe data in `idType` column contain some invisible character (at the
start / in the middle / at the end)?
Try to execute e.g. `logs.idType.str.startswith('5c6c189')`.
You should get a boolean *Series* with *True* values at the "found" positions. Compare the result with the column in question, whether "proper" rows have corresponding *True* result.
Then, step by step, make the criterion string longer and run the command again.
If at some point you get all *False* results, then there is something wrong at the "corresponding" position.

Comment: Note that *idType* column contains only **hex** digits.
What is the type of this column?
Your program is based on assumption that the type is *string*
(in Pandas - *Object*), but maybe this column is of **other** type
and the hex content we see is only a **representation** of the true value?

Comment: When i print the result of the line of code you just gave me it display a Series of 'NaN'. And I have verified and the column is object Type